# How do I see how long the current phone call has lasted so far

Tags: iphone, call, voice

Basically as the title.

The scenario is that on a phone call would like to see how long I have been on it.

I am on an IPhone SE (second generation) IOS 15

I think on old iOS it was shown on screen.

(Asked when hanging on a support line :))

Answer (score 2):

This is still the case in recent iOS versions, and it's automatically displayed below the name / number of the person you're calling. (Here it's been 3 seconds since the call started)

[image: original is from https://www.applemust.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/facetimecall.jpg but I edited to add red rectangle]

<sup>The above screenshot was taken on an iPhone running iOS 15 (as asked in the question). With iOS 16, the design has changed a bit but the call time is still beneath the person's name/number.</sup>

Comment: How do you get that screen  after you have switched screens e.g. to use the keypad

Comment: When you switch to the keypad view @mmmmmm, press “Hide” to come back to this screen.